# The number of distinct real roots of the folllowing determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant, roots

> The number of distinct real roots of determinant $$
>         \begin{vmatrix}
>         \csc x & \sec x & \sec x \\
>         \sec x & \csc x & \sec x \\
>         \sec x & \sec x & \csc x \\
>         \end{vmatrix}
> =0$$ lies in the interval $\frac{-\pi}{4} \le x \le \frac{\pi}{4}$ is 
> (a) $1$   
> (b) $2$ 
> (c) $3$ 
> (d) $0$

I tried to solve the determinant and solved it till I got:

 $$(\csc x + 2\sec x)(\csc x - \sec x)^2=0$$

How do I get the final answer?
Please offer your assistance,
 Thank you

Comment: The first factor is 0 if and only if $\cos(x) + 2\sin(x) = 0$ and $\sin(x) \neq 0, \cos(x) \neq 0$; the second is 0 iff $\cos(x) - \sin(x) = 0$ and $\sin(x) \neq 0, \cos(x) \neq 0$. Can you solve these equations?

Comment: No that is what i want

Comment: For the first write $u = \cos(x)$ so that $\sin(x) = \sqrt{1-u^2}$. The equation becomes $u + 2\sqrt{1-u^2} = 0$, re-arranging and squaring one gets $u^2 = 4(1-u^2)$. Solve the equation and see which of the solutions is valid. Note that the second is equivalent to $\tan(x) = 1$, i.e. $x = \pi/4, 3\pi/4$. Pick the one which lies in the given interval.

Comment: @snarski Can you convert your comment into an answer so this doesn't remain unanswered?

Answer (score 1):

We need to solve $\cos(x) + 2\sin(x) = 0$ and $\cos(x) - \sin(x) = 0$. The first equation is solved by setting $u = \cos(x)$ and solving for $u$, i.e.
\begin{align*}
u+2\sqrt{1-u^2} &= 0\\
u &= -2\sqrt{1-u^2} \\
u^2 &= 4(1-u^2) \\
5u^2 &= 4
\end{align*}
and checking which values of $\cos^{-1}(\pm 2/\sqrt{5})$ lie in the specified interval. For the second equation, only $x = \pi/4$ works.

Answer (score 0):

For the root of given determinant, you need either $\csc x+2\sec x=0$ or $\csc x-\sec x=0$.

i.e. $\tan x=-1/2$ or $tan x=1$

As $\tan x$ is bijective in $(-\pi/4,\pi/4)$ so both conditions give you a unique value of $x$ in prescribed interval. Hence the correct answer is $2$.